# Why Warp command can't work in batch processing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, actions, warp

Edit>Transform>Warp seems the only command that can'be played in a batch. Why? Any workaround?

Comment: what software??

Comment: @Scott, it's Photoshop, thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You can record a warp transform in an action in the latest version of Photoshop, and you can apply that action using File > Automate > Batch.

Comment: It has always been possible to record, but when playing the action, the batch stops on that command with the message "Transform command not available". Release 25.4.0. Thank you @BillyKerr